# Django, dynamic forms and Ajax

Tags: javascript, django

I'm creating a website using django, with a form allowing students to ask for a certain room at a certain hour (which are already predefined), and for a certain amount of time.
For exemple, every classroom can be taken for 30 minutes, so you can ask a classroom in the liste:
["Classroom A", "Classroom B", Classroom C"] in one of the hours ["8:00", "8:30", "9:00"].
However I want my form to be such that, if someone already asked Classroom B at 8:00, when Classroom B is selected, the choices are narrowed to 8:30 an 9:00. (the choice of the time is hidden until a classroom is selected).

My question is: how, using javascript with ajax or not, can I be able to access my models and removing the unusable choices?
(My form is a modelform)

Thanks

Comment: You can create a view that returns in plain JSON the choices available, so when you click the ckeckbox or the group box or whatever, you can call a javascript method that use an asynchronous GET to verify the choices. The tricky part is that you can not "use" the model using Javascript but on the other hand, you can access to the data if it is available as a view with is own parameters

Comment: So I get them in JSON thanks to a view, and then use some simple javascript to add or remove options from the <select> ?

Comment: Yep,that's how I use to do it, let's see if the community has a better method